# What does !a&&(a||b) simplify to?

Tags: language-agnostic, boolean-logic

I'm a little confused on `!a&&(a||b)`. If I look at it directly and interpret it simply, it appears as if it is the same as

```
!a&&a or !a&&b
```

but this seems a little weird because since `a` can't be true and false, it would only be true if the latter was true. I also interpreted it like this

```
!a || a&&b
```

I don't really know how I came up with this one but it just looks more logical since there are no contradictions. Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: `!a&&a` is just false, so you're just left with `!a&&b`.

Comment: Note that this assumes that `a` is a variable (and that it can't be modified by another thread in the middle of evaluating the expression).  If `a` is a method call, it could be called twice, so you can't always simplify it.

Comment: Note that your final interpretation will be true if `a` and `b` are both true, unlike in the original.

Comment: This is mis-tagged. This is not about Java and simply about Boolean logic.

Comment: @ajb That is true, but I can't see an actual use case where it matters.  If it matters, you should probably synchronize your code.

Comment: @FlorianF: The point is that if `a` changes value between the two references to it, then the expression can evaluate to `true` even if `b` is `false`. (And -- yes, you should synchronize your code.)

Comment: @ajb: [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) hold if and only if the expressions consist only of [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). Threading does not matter.

Comment: @LieRyan: The question was edited by someone else than the OP. The original question specifically asked about Java, which is both impure and concurrent.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Language is irrelevant. You can have pure functions in any languages, even those with concurrency.

Comment: @ruakh I understand that `!a&&a` can be true in this particular cases.  But code that relies on `a` occasionally changing during the evaluation has a problem.  By the way, code that works correctly with `!a&&(a||b)` when `a` doesn't change will also work with `!a&&b` where `a` cannot change.

Comment: @FlorianF: Well, obviously. :-)

Comment: @LieRyan: No one is saying that Boolean algebra is *irrelevant* to an understanding of the Java expression `!a&&(a||b)`; indeed, the Java expression `!a&&(a||b)` usually *does* represent a pure Boolean expression. ajb's point, and Jörg W Mittag's point, is that the Java expression `!a&&(a||b)` does not *necessarily* represent a pure Boolean expression.

Comment: @ruakh: and my point is that concurrency or language is superfluous and a red herring. Boolean algebra works if and only if the entire expression is composed solely of pure functions/expressions. That is the only property that needs to hold during the evaluation for the transformation to be valid, not "no concurrent modifications", or "no method calls", or what not.

Comment: @LieRyan: Purity or impurity is a *result* of properties such as concurrent modifications, method calls, etc., in a language-specific way. You can certainly argue that one way or a different way is the best way to explain it or the most general way to present it, but it's nonsense to say that one way is "superfluous" and "a red herring" simply because you'd rather phrase it a different way!

Comment: @LieRyan I'm not sure its up to us to say what is or isn't a red herring.  If someone stumbles across this question in the future (and that's what StackOverflow is for), I don't want them to get confused and think `!someMethod()&&(someMethod()||someOtherMethod())` can be simplified.  That's why I felt it useful to add my comment.  Of course the real solution is not to write code like that.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

#### Tautology Table

```
 | a | b | !a | a || b |  !a && (a || b)  | !a && b | [ !a && (a || b) ] <=> [!a && b]    |
 |---|---|----|--------|------------------|---------|-------------------------------------|
 | 0 | 0 |  1 |   0    |      0           |    0    |                   1                 |
 | 0 | 1 |  1 |   1    |      1           |    1    |                   1                 |
 | 1 | 0 |  0 |   1    |      0           |    0    |                   1                 |
 | 1 | 1 |  0 |   1    |      0           |    0    |                   1                 |
```

#### "Proof"

1. According to the [Principle of Distributivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_distributivity) statement `!a && (a || b)` is equivalent to `(!a && a) || (!a && b)`.
2. Accordiong to the [Law of Non-Contradiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_noncontradiction) `(!a && a)` is equivalent to `false`
3. Putting it all together:

   `!a && (a || b) <=> (!a && a) || (!a && b) <=> false || (!a && b) <=> !a && b`

Comment: I really like this, but I'm confused on the last column - what is the <=>? I'm not familiar with this operator...equivalence?

Comment: Yes, <=> stands for equivalence (or bidirectional implication in other words)

Comment: @BrianDHall `a <=> b` means `(!a || b) && (!b || a)`.

Comment: @Bakuriu @BrianDHall More precisely, it means that `(!a || b) && (!b || a)` evaluates to `true`. It is a definitive statement, not merely a proposition.

Answer (score 12):

You can simplify it like this `(!a && b)` because in expression `(!a && a || !a && b)` the condition `!a && a` is always false

Answer (score 11):

[In Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) like in most <sup>1</sup> languages the unary `!` has higher precedence than `&&`.

So `!a&&(a||b)` *is* `(!a)&&(a||b)`

You can represent the truth table of that expression using a [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map):

```
      | a = 0 | a = 1 |
------+-------+-------+
b = 0 |   0   |   0   |
------+-------+-------+
b = 1 |   1   |   0   |
------+-------+-------+
```

Now, it can easily be *seen* that the only true case is when `(!a) && b`.

So `!a&&(a||b)` *is* `!a && b`

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>See comments below.</sub>

Comment: I've *never* seen a language where `NOT` has a lower precedence than `AND` or `OR`. Have you?

Comment: @Bergi You're right. Shame on me ... After your comment, I've spend at least 30 minutes trying to find a language having a `not` operator with a lower precedence than `and`. Maybe such language exists but I wasn't able to find it. I've edited my answer to remove that nonsense. Thank you for pointing that out !

Comment: @Bergi Yes, there is a language, sort of: APL (as implemented on IBM systems way back when).  There's actually no precedence at all--everything is right to left.  So `!A&&B` would actually be interpreted as `!(A&&B)`, not `(!A)&&B`.  (APL didn't use those symbols for the operators; I don't remember what the actual symbols were, but probably something that's not on any normal keyboard.)

Comment: @Bergi I though about APL yesterday, but wasn't able to test. Trying this morning it appears that it behave like you explained it: [`~1∧0` is evaluated to `1` -- not `0`](http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/#code=%7E1%u22270).

Comment: Upvoted, This is a much more concise answer than the (current) top answer.

Comment: @ajb: Thanks :-) Actually I had expected that there are such languages without special precedence rules (like [reverse] polish notation), only I didn't knew one.

Answer (score 6):

It simply means `!a && b`, a must be false and b must be true, for it to be true

Answer (score 4):

`(!a && a) || (!a && b)` is a correct expansion of this (using the distributive law).

This can be simplified to `!a && b`.

The distributive laws for Boolean algebra are:

```
a && (b || c) == (a && b) || (a && c)
a || (b && c) == (a || b) && (a || c)
```

Answer (score 3):

`!a && (a || b)` can be considered with a binary truth table,

> ```
> a       b       out
> true    true    false
> false   true    true
> false   false   false
> true    false   false
> ```

So the only circumstance that passes is

```
 (!a && b)
```

and we could apply DeMorgan's laws to that and get

```
 !(a || !b)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you use Wolfram alpha for simplifications like these, it can be amazing what it can do to your expressions sometimes. This particular expression simplifies to `!a && b`

Link to WA: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%21a%26%26%28a%7C%7Cb%29

Comment: WA yields the direct result if you tell it to *simplify*: [WA: simplify `!a && (a || b)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+%21a+%26%26+%28a+%7C%7C+b%29).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it'll simplify to just

```
!a && b
```

If you open up the parenthesis you'll have

```
(!a && a) || (!a && b)
```

The 1st part (!a && a) is always false so you can just omit it.

Answer (score 2):

I am presuming the "or" is of lower precedence (normally boolean logic && or || are equal and as such this would've been ambiguous

```
  !a&&a or !a&&b
= (!a&&a) || (!a && b)
= false || (!a && b) 
      // because X and not X will never be true for any combination of X
= (!a && b)
      // because false || X == X for any value of X
= !a && b
      // removed parens
```